# Is it possible to create Stellar Assets that are private?

Tags: token, assets

I'm evaluating using the Stellar Network for a project and would like to know if it is possible to create and issue assets that are private, that is, assets that:

- Can only be issued to specific individuals or groups of people
- Won't appear on SDEX, unless specifically indicated
- Can control their inflation rate

Additional specific resources or recommended tutorials on Stellar assets are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes. (See the Stellar website below.)
2. And if you don't set an offer it will not be listed on sdex.
3. I don't know what this means... You are the only one who can issue the asset so you are in full control of the "inflation".

[Issuing Assets | Stellar Developer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html#requiring-or-revoking-authorization)

> Requiring or Revoking Authorization Accounts have several flags
>   related to issuing assets. Setting the AUTHORIZATION REVOCABLE flag
>   allows you to freeze assets you issued in case of theft or other
>   special circumstances. This can be useful for national currencies, but
>   is not always applicable to other kinds of assets.
>
> If your asset is special purpose or you’d like to control who can be
>   paid with it, use the AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED flag, which requires that
>   the issuing account also approves a trustline before the receiving
>   account is allowed to be paid with the asset.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding point 3, for example: I'm an Anchor and issue asset "A" and want "A" to have an inflation rate of 10% annually for all the asset "A" holders.

Comment: then you just have to issue 10% more token per anno. Thats up to you. The issuing account can issue as much tokens as it wants if the token holders have trustlines with corresponding trustlimits